# Georeferencing two images at same time in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, imagery

Has anyone ever tried to georeference two images at the same time on QGIS?

In my application I don't atually care much about the positioning itself, but in the scale and orientation.

I have GeoTIFFs of aerial views of buildings. Unfortunately these images do not have a complete picture of the buildings (low flight drone). I would like to "construct" the complete picture of a building use various parts. These parts are already georeferenced, but due to small errors in the GPS positioning, we do see discontinuation failures on the seams. I don't care about the positioning itself during this construction, as I can later position the complete picture when done.

I'm not sure if I'm using the correct tool, but in QGIS there is the georeferencer. It seems to be able to rotate and move images as I want, but only one image at a time. This isn't ideal for me as I'm trying to assemble what is essentially a puzzle.

Comment: I don't know the imaging conditions of both images, but maybe you might try to stitch them first. Afterwards you georeference the stitched image. I must admit this is a dirty solution...

Comment: @kadéem how would you stitch them?

Comment: If you have access to Erdas Imagine, I can recommend the Mosaic tool. It's software typically used for processing satellite or aerial imagery. And expensive. Other non-geospatial solutions: Photoshop, Microsoft ICE and Hugin. The last two tools are free. Mind the settings: don't create panoramic images as it will deform your aerial imagery.